# Regex refactoring - Search for match and if found replace it in one line

Tags: c#, regex

Hello I am learning regex and I need a sum of your intelligence to solve this problem.

I need to know if I can search somewhere for match of some word and if matched I put whole article to match collection then I search in every item in collection by `foreach` and replacing the keyword with another... this code work but I need to know if is possible to do that without `foreach` because its wasting of memory....

```
MatchCollection mc;
List<string> listek = new List<string>();

Regex r = new Regex(@".*" + word + @".*");

mc = r.Matches(text);
foreach (var item in mc)
{
    listek.Add(Regex.Replace(item.ToString(), word, @"<span class=""highlighted"">" + word + "</span>"));
}
```

---

I have the following XML:

```
<article>
    <title>title 1</title>
    <text>some long text</text>
</article>
<article>
    <title>title 2</title>
    <text>some long text</text>
</article>
```

I need to search for keyword in every text node and if i found match i need to return article witch replaced keywords... my code showed up do it but dummy way..(@".*" + word + @".*") this mean that i adding to collection whole text but only if contains my keyword i would like to replace the keywords in same time and i dont know how

---

I solved it like this:

```
internal static string SearchWordInXml()
{
    var all = from a in WordBase.Descendants("ITEM")
    select new
    {
        title = a.Element("TITLE").Value,
        text = a.Element("TEXT").Value
                  };
        foreach (var d in all)
        {
            Regex r = new Regex(@".*" + service.word + @".*");
            Match v = r.Match(d.text);
            Template();
            var xElemData = TempBase.XPathSelectElement("//DATA");
            if (v.Success)
            {
                XElement elemSet = new XElement("DATASET");
                XElement elemId = new XElement("DATAPIECE");
                XAttribute attId = new XAttribute("ATT", "TITLE");
                XAttribute valueId = new XAttribute("VALUE", d.title);
                elemSet.Add(elemId);
                elemId.Add(attId);
                elemId.Add(valueId);
                XElement elemName = new XElement("DATAPIECE");
                XAttribute attName = new XAttribute("ATT", "TEXT");
                XAttribute valueName = new XAttribute("VALUE", Regex.Replace(d.text, service.word, @"<span class=""highlighted"">" + service.word + "</span>"));
                xElemData.Add(elemSet);
                elemSet.Add(elemName);
                elemName.Add(attName);
                elemName.Add(valueName);
            }
        }
    return convert(TempBase);
}
```

Comment: is the list intended to contain all of the replacements?

Comment: this code works i just wanna refactor it in best way replace all matches in text before adding to colection so i could avoid using of list and foreach

Comment: To help you find a more efficient solution we'd need to know what you want to achieve, because from from your example it's not clear. Do you want to add your spans into your original text?

Comment: I have XML file with nodes like this <article><title>title 1</title><text>some long text</text></article><article><title>title 2</title><text>some long text</text></article> i need to search for keyword in  every text node and if i found match i need to return article witch replaced keywords... my code showed up do it but dummy way..(@".*" + word + @".*") this mean that i adding to collection whole text but only if contains my keyword i would like to replace the keywords in sime time and i dont know how

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking into text nodes, I would probaby go with something like this

```
string text = "<article><title>title 1</title><text>some long text</text></article><article><title>title 2</title><text>some long text</text></article>";
string word = "long";
Regex r = new Regex("(?<=<text>.*?)"+word+"(?=.*?</text>)");
text = r.Replace(text, "<span class=\"highlighted\">$&</span>");
```

Text will now contains only you correct values.

Note that the `$&` is a backreference to the full match. If you would any kind of grouping (use of parenthesis `()`) you could use `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.

To only have one line you can use

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "(?<=<text>.*?)"+word+"(?=.*?</text>)","<span class=\"highlighted\">$&</span>");
```